# jQuery changing background on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code

## html

```
<div id="addQuesion">
    <ul id="aQul">
        <li class="aQli"></li>
        <li class="aQli"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my jQuery is

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".aQli").mouseover(function(){

    });
    $(".aQli").mouseout(function(){

    });
});
```

I want when hovering over a li, the background should be red, and on exit from that li, the background should return to white.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have to use jQuery?

The more "correct" way would be to add a hover style to your class.

```
.aQli:hover{
   background-color: red;   
}​
```

See here for an example.  http://jsfiddle.net/maurice_butler/5q6QM/

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify this to use .hover():

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".aQli").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background", "#F00");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css("background", "#FFF");
    });
});
```

The first function runs for mouseover and the second for mouseout.  The .css() function sets a CSS property, in this case a background color on the hovered element.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){
    $(".aQli").on('mouseover', 'li', function(){  //using "on" for optimization
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';       //native JS application
    }).on('mouseout', 'li', function(){           //chain to avoid second selector call
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';     //native JS application
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I came up two ways to do that by using jQuery.
One way is to use jQuery to change the css directly, using .css() to set the background color.

```
//css
ul#aQul li{
  display : inline-block;
  padding : 5px;
  margin : 5px;
}

//javascript use jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".aQli").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css({
        "background-color" :　"red",
        "cursor" : "pointer"
    });
 });
 $(".aQli").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css({
        "background-color" : "transparent",
        "cursor" : "default"
    });

 });
});​​
```

The other way is using jQuery to add a specific class attribute if hover happens, and there is a specific css rule to change the background color.

```
//css, need to specify the state of hover
 ul#aQul li.hover{     //li elements which have "hover" class
   cursor:pointer;
   background-color : red;
 }

//javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".aQli").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover")      //hover, add class "hover"
 });
 $(".aQli").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover");  //hover out, remove class "hover"

 });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(ENETR URL HERE)");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css("background", "#FFF");
    });
});
```

```css
.box{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>
<body>


  <div class="box">
    
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```