# mouseover not working when appending dynamically li to ul

Tags: jquery

I followed the code that zhujy_8833 posted on this page, [jQuery changing background on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526121/jquery-changing-background-on-hover).

It works fine as it is but when I dynamically append li to ul using jQuery. My mouseover doesn't fire on li.
I am looping over some data that I pull from my database and append them to ul as follow:

**In HTML I have:**

```
<div id="result-holder">
    <ul id="results-list">
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JQuery for populaing the ul:**

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    // #results-list is the ul id
    $('#results-list').append("<li class='lineInc' id='lineInc_"+i+"'>" + data[i] + "</li>");
}
```

**Trying to change li background color using**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".lineInc").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).addClass("hover")      //hover, add class "hover"
    });
    $(".lineInc").mouseout(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("hover");  //hover out, remove class "hover"
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul#results-list .lineInc.hover{ 
      cursor:pointer;
      background:#900;
}
```

Also, I tried this CSS but still not working

```
ul#results-list li.hover{ 
      cursor:pointer;
      background:#900;
}
```

Can you please help me on this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#results-list").on("mouseover", ".lineInc" ,function(){
            $(this).addClass("hover")      //hover, add class "hover"
    });
    $("#results-list").on("mouseout", ".lineInc",function(){
            $(this).removeClass("hover");  //hover out, remove class "hover"
    });
});
```